# centos 7 конфликт библиотек mysql и mariadb

Tags: mysql, администрирование, perl, mariadb, yum

Цель собственно 1 - обеспечить perl возможностью работать с oracle mysql.

`yum install libdbi-dbd-mysql` требует установки зависимости - mariadb-libs

---

```
Зависимости определены

==========================================================================================================================================
 Package                               Архитектура                 Версия                                 Репозиторий               Размер
==========================================================================================================================================
Установка:
 libdbi-dbd-mysql                      x86_64                      0.8.3-16.el7                           base                       17 k
Установка зависимостей:
 mariadb-libs                          x86_64                      1:5.5.64-1.el7                         base                      759 k

Итого за операцию
==========================================================================================================================================
Установить  1 пакет (+1 зависимый)

Общий размер: 776 k
Объем изменений: 4.4 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:

  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.1.73-1.glibc23.x86_64

  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.1.73-1.glibc23.x86_64

  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.1.73-1.glibc23.x86_64

  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.1.73-1.glibc23.x86_64
......
```

---

В системе работает oracle mysql..
Собственно как быть? Базу переставить невозможно. Конфликтующие в пакетах файлы идентичны до байта. 
Может есть какой-то другой пакет libdbi-dbd-mysql не требующий mariadb, а mysqldb?

Comment: `yum install perl-DBD-MySQL` ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/381018/292034 , а вообще, конечно, не стоит устанавливать «левые» пакеты (речь про MySQL-server-5.1.73-1.glibc23).